# get value of c# array session in javascript

Tags: javascript, c#

I would like to know how I can get the javascript values ​​of a C # Session variable that contains an array of strings. The code is as follows: **C #:**

```
if (Session["PolizasClientes_RowID"] != null)
{
  Session.Remove("PolizasClientes_RowID");
}
var array = lstPolizas.Where(x => x.POLIZA == row_id).Select(x => x.DNI).ToArray();
var array2 = lstPolizas.Where(x => x.POLIZA == row_id).Select(x => x.POLIZA).ToArray();
string dni= array[0];
string poliza = array2[0];

string[] arrays = new string[] { dni, poliza };
Session["PolizasClientes_RowID"] = arrays;
```

**javascript**::

```
var valores_sesion = '<%=Session["PolizasClientes_RowID"]%>';
//return System.string[] :
console.log(valores_sesion);
//return S
console.log(valores_sesion[0]);
//reurn S
console.log(valores_sesion[0][0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use some JSON framework like Newtonsoft Json.NET, for instance. Install it using NuGet and then serialize your array into JSON like this:

```
var valores_sesion = <%=JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Session["PolizasClientes_RowID"])%>;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var valores_sesion = <%= new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Session("PolizasClientes_RowID")) %>;
```

try this

Comment: Ok i did. But now, how i can get 1 value of the result? ["37281598R","ALL150291-08"]